# Android underline textview via selector

Tags: android, textview, selector, underline

I have a question about a TextView. I want the textview to change its style when pressed to underlined. Like the colorchange with an selector. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this inside button click.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
SpannableString content = new SpannableString("Content");
content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
tv.setText(content);
```

or try this one

```
textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags()| Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);
```

Comment: Thx but after i go back to the activity where the TextView is shwowing the TextView is still underlined. I want it to react like a selector. Like pressed state true -> underlined. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

inside a button click ,you have to do like this.......

textview.setPaintFlags(Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

Answer (score 0):

This approach can be used to underline full width of your TextView, irrespective of the contained text length inside.

Set the TextView `android:background` property to custom selector drawable.

Custom selector with an underline may be composed using the approach with a `<layer-list>`, that includes a rectangle shape with top, left and right borders offscreen (via negative padding).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <!-- Not pressed state, consider adding other focused state here -->
  <item android:state_pressed="false">
    <layer-list>
      <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>

  <!-- Pressed state would be processed here, and show an underline -->
  <item>
    <layer-list>
      <item android:left="-3dp" android:right="-3dp" android:top="-3dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
          <stroke android:width="1.5dp" android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_dark" />
          <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        </shape>
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
</selector>
```